# Python Tornado - disable logging to stderr

Tags: python, tornado

I have minimalistic Tornado application:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class PingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("pong\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([ ("/ping", PingHandler), ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Tornado keeps reporting error requests to stderr:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.79ms
```

**Question:** It want to prevent it from logging error messages. How?

Tornado version 3.1; Python 2.6

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Its clear that "someone" is initializing logging subsystem when we start Tornado. Here is the code from `ioloop.py` that reveals the mystery:

```
def start(self):
    if not logging.getLogger().handlers:
        # The IOLoop catches and logs exceptions, so it's
        # important that log output be visible.  However, python's
        # default behavior for non-root loggers (prior to python
        # 3.2) is to print an unhelpful "no handlers could be
        # found" message rather than the actual log entry, so we
        # must explicitly configure logging if we've made it this
        # far without anything.
        logging.basicConfig()
```

`basicConfig` is called and configures default `stderr` handler.

So to setup proper logging for tonado access, you need to:

1. Add a handler to `tornado.access` logger: `logging.getLogger("tornado.access").addHandler(...)`
2. Disable propagation for the above logger: `logging.getLogger("tornado.access").propagate = False`. Otherwise messages will arrive BOTH to your handler AND to `stderr`

Comment: Can you share an example how to addHandler?

Answer (score 17):

The previous answer was correct, but a little incomplete. This will send everything to the NullHandler:

```
hn = logging.NullHandler()
hn.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("tornado.access").addHandler(hn)
logging.getLogger("tornado.access").propagate = False
```

Comment: Where is the code for the default handler? How can I suppress only a specific case of a specfic error code?

Answer (score 9):

You could also quite simply (in one line) do:

```
logging.getLogger('tornado.access').disabled = True
```

Comment: it does work for me. It helped me to avoid save tornado info log message into my log file. Thanks