# Tornado - No handlers could be found for logger "tornado.application" while using render()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

```
from tornado.web import RequestHandler

class HelloWorldHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # self.write("Hello, world...!!!")  # works without any error
        self.render('hello.html') # but here I get:
        # `500: Internal Server Error` and my console shows `No handlers
        # could be found for logger "tornado.application" `.
```

What is the issue? I've already Googled [*No handlers could be found for logger "tornado.application"*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=No+handlers+could+be+found+for+logger+%22tornado.application%22&oq=No+handlers+could+be+found+for+logger+%22tornado.application%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.398j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8).

and surprisingly all urls suggest same method but I'm unable to implement this.
here is same thread on [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234772/python-tornado-disable-logging-to-stderr).

Answer (score 3):

If your logs were configured correctly you'd get a stack trace in the logs that would explain what went wrong. The logs are supposed to be configured automatically in IOLoop.start() so I'm not sure why that's not happening, but you can configure them manually by calling logging.basicConfig() or tornado.options.parse_command_line() at the beginning of main.